# Is this a sufficient condition for convexity?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, monotone-functions

Let $f: [a,\infty) \to \Bbb R$ be a nonincreasing function such that for all $t> s \geq a$ and all $c>0$ holds that
$$f(s+c) + f(t) \leq f(t+c) +f(s)$$

Does this imply that $f$ is convex ?

For a statement of a book, where the proof was omitted, this or a similar implication is necessary, I guess.

I found [Does increasing differences imply convexity of a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3119814/does-increasing-differences-imply-convexity-of-a-function) which shows that without the monotonocity the statement woul be false. But with monotonocity the counterexample of this post doe not work anymore, since $f$ has at most countable discontinuous then, and if it was additionally additive it would follow that it is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does imply $f$ is convex.  For $a \le p < q$, take $s=p$, $c=(q-p)/2$, $t = (p+q)/2$, so your inequality says $2 f((p+q)/2) \le f(q) + f(p)$, i.e. $f$ is midpoint-convex.  Any monotone midpoint-convex function is convex.